# Why is this code not working?

Tags: asp.net, webmethod

I am trying to add a search bar with an auto complete in asp.net using a web method and here is what i tried :

```
 <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="sBox"></asp:TextBox>

        <asp:AutoCompleteExtender runat="server" ID="aC" TargetControlID="sBox"
            MinimumPrefixLength="2" Enabled="true" EnableCaching="true"
                CompletionInterval="0000" CompletionSetCount="20"
                    ServiceMethod="AutoComplete" ServicePath="~/Controls/SearchComplete.asmx"
                ></asp:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

and the web-method:

```
    [WebMethod]
public string[] AutoComplete(string prefixText) //auto completing the searchbar
{
    List<string> listString = new List<string>();

    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"ConnectionString"))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT id,name FROM search WHERE name LIKE @name", conn);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", "%" + prefixText + "%");

        conn.Open();

        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        if (dr.HasRows) 
        {
            while (dr.Read()) 
            {
                listString.Add(AutoCompleteExtender.CreateAutoCompleteItem(dr["name"].ToString(), dr["id"].ToString()));
            }
        }
    }

    string[] str = listString.ToArray();
    return str;
}
```

**it's not giving errors it just isn't auto completing**  , thanks

using asp.net 4.0

Comment: What exactly is "not working"? It really helps to clarify such open-ended statements...

Comment: Give us a clue - what is it doing?  What is it not doing?  Are there any error messages?

Comment: @erOx - main question updated

Comment: Is the database connection working? Is anything being returned from the database? Does it enter the dr.HasRows branch?

Comment: Have you tried setting the `CompletionInterval` property to something other than "0000"?

Comment: @jwiscarson - Yes tried many different numbers but same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things to check for:

1) check to see if there's data going TO the server

2) put a break point on the "return" statement to checked what's being returned from the query

Comment: "return" statement woks fine it returns everything as it should

Comment: ok, check to see what the data that comes back looks like in the browse. I use Chrome and you see the data by going in the Inspector then click the Network tab. When you call the auto-complete, you will see the call in the left column (name column). Click that and see what goes up and what comes back.

Comment: nothing goes up, i think the auto complete request doesn't get submitted.

Comment: Then that's where the problem comes from; do you have a Script Manager tag on your aspx page? Also, for the moment, try to disable the caching on the control.

Comment: disabled caching but it still no luck, and yes i have a script manager

Comment: Then I would move the textbox, the auto-complete and the back-end stuff on another page with nothing else on it and try to make that part work. Sometimes, it's also interactions with other things on the page that create problems.

Comment: also, add this line just above the first line of the web service class definition of the code behind file, just after all the using statements you might have: [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]

Comment: Tried moving to a new blank website and tried to add the line but still nothing works

Comment: Man... we've all been there. Here's something else to try: make a call to the web service WITHOUT the control; see if that works. You can use JQuery.ajax to send the same info the auto-complete control would send, and see what you get back. Also, what's the CompletionInterval parameter for? Try changing every parameter to see if that makes a difference

Comment: i tried to use JQuery.ajax but still no request is sent, and i think the CompletionInterval is the delay between typing and sending the request.

Comment: just removed the ajax toolkit and reinstalled via nuGet and it worked, thanks

Comment: ok, cool. I just got rid of the MS Ajax framework altogether and am hand-writing everything I need. It's much faster and much much more scalable. Check this out: http://encosia.com/why-aspnet-ajax-updatepanels-are-dangerous/

Comment: my use of the ajax framework is really quite rare, i usually just use jquery.

Comment: Did you manage to get it working? I agree with, jquery and hand-built components are the way to go. Else you spend days figuring out what's not workng; might as well put that time into building your own stuff.

Comment: i guess you are right - building you own components also gives you full control which is needed most of the time.

Comment: Not to mention that your control includes ONLY the features you need; compared to plug-ins that contain all sorts of functionalities you don't need for your particular case.

Comment: true - i agree with you building your own components is the best way to get things done right

Answer (score 0):

Set a break point in `AutoComplete()` and debug it. You may be throwing an error server side which prevents the client side AutoCompleteExtender from seeing the web method return value.